# If an app is only for iPhone, where does the iPad pull it's 1x/2x version from?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Does it use the iPhone 6 Plus version? Where does it get it from?

I ask because I have been building my app based on screen dimensions. iPad's have different screen dimension ratios so I decided to make my app iPhone only. However, when I run my app on an iPad the positioning of everything is totally screwed up! But when I run it on every other iPhone device (from 5 to 6s plus because iPhone 4 dimensions are off) it looks fine!

So where does it get it's version from? Does it pull from the iPhone 4?

Answer (score 3):

Every app can run on the iPad no matter if it is supported or not. If the app is NOT built for iPad (iPhone only) - it would show up as it shows up on an iPhone 4. Be sure that your screens support iPhone 4 or you won't make it past the app review process (annoying but true).

From the Apple iOS App Store Review Guidelines (https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

**2.10 iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution**

Comment: So am I just screwed? I have been using a specific function to scale my numbers for me and its all based on the phone's width but the iphone 4 has the same width but different height!

Comment: Start using autolayout and stop using CGRectMake

Comment: This isn’t valid as of now (it’s been 4yrs I know), but I couldn’t find anything more on that. still digging, but if anyone has any updates would be great.